Nginx returning 502 timeout within milliseconds
Our production implementation looks like this
Internet-Facing-ALB ---> Nginx-Cluster-On-Ec2 ----> Internal-ALB --> Application Ec2
We are sometime getting 502 timeout error within a milliseconds even if the application server are working fine. When we do restart of nginx things start to work perfectly fine. Before getting the 502 timeout error we get warning in nginx error log.
2024/04/15 06:40:11 [warn] 1406177#1406177: *19538082 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 12.34.566.55, server: _, request: "POST /axb/api/v1/status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://12.34.34.4:80/axb/api/v1/status ", host: "test@abc.com"


2024/04/15 06:40:11 [error] 1406177#1406177: *19538082 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 12.34.566.55, server: _, request: "POST /axb/api/v1/status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://12.34.34.4:80/axb/api/v1/status", host: "test@abc.com"

Below is the nginx configuration server block
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name _;

    client_body_buffer_size     10M;
    client_max_body_size 24000M;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_connect_timeout      60;
    proxy_send_timeout         60;
    proxy_read_timeout         300;
   
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://12.34.34.4:80;
     }
}

Please let us know what can be done to solve this problem.
